# React-javascript : My react input isn't working. It becomes immutable once i set the Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

My react input component becomes uneditable once I set the value to my state component

```
state = {text: ''}



return(
                   <input id="search" 
                   type="text"
                   value={this.state.text}
                    onChange={e => this.setState = ({text: e.target.value })}/>
)
```

Once I comment out the value it works fine though.

Comment: `this.setState = ({text: e.target.value }` should be `this.setState({text: e.target.value }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setState incorrectly, setState is a function which expects parameters to be passed inside to update the state, you cannot assign a function with values.

here is an example below which should fix your issues.

```
state = {text: ''}

return(
         <input id="search" 
          type="text"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={e => this.setState({text: e.target.value })}/>
)
```